# R.java file deleting itself

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a slight issue. When I add items to the menu.xml file, the R.java file in the gen folder does not generate. I've used the same code before and no problems have arisen. I am using Eclipse with the ADT plugin on Windows 7.

Here is the menu.xml file code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.andrewq.planets.MainActivity" >

    <item android:id="@+id/action_about"
        android:icon="@drawable/action_about"
        android:title="@string/action_about"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

And here is the code used in MainActivity.java:

```
//Method used to inflate the menu
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

//Method used to add items to the menu
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_about:
            aboutMenuItem();
            break;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Settings.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

FYI -- Here is some Manifest information:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

EDIT: The problem seems to arise when the items are added to the menu.xml files. If I delete the items, it just says it can't find `action_about` or `action_settings` whereas when the items are there the R.java file disappears.

EDIT #2: Here are some screenshots of code setup:

> Here is a picture of the XML code with the items commented out.

[image: XML Items commented out]

> And the Java code while items are commented out says that it can't
>   find action_settings or action_about:

[image: Java code while commented out]

> And finally, the errors output while items are commented out:

[image: errors while commented out]

Now if I take the comment brackets out like so:

[image: uncommented]

The following errors arise which can't seem to be solved:

[image: uncommented errors]

I hope this can help someone solve my problem. I've never had this problem before.

Thanks, 
Andrew

Comment: Are you using eclipse?

Comment: You mean to say R.java is not generating automatically? Because R.java generates automatically if the setting is Auto Build in Project menu option of Eclipse.

Comment: I'm using the ADT Bundle, so yes.

Comment: what is the **minSdk** of your application??

Comment: @ghostbust555 -- I've edited my question accordingly.

Comment: @Namecan'tbedisplayed -- Minimum SDK: 11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not deleting itself, it's not getting generated for the changes that you've made. So I suggest you clean the project, rebuild it, and if it still shows issues, go to the console and check the issues. If nothing shows there, open problems view and check it. Surely it will suggest some errors. Please take a look at error log too.

EDIT:
remove showAsAction="never" from menu if your using API 11 or below or set min SDK version to 11 in manifest file.

Comment: AFTER EDIT: Still doesn't work. Also look at the edited version of my question.

Comment: app:showAsAction="never" change this to andoid:showAsAction="never"

Comment: that was already suggested and done with "Tabrej Khan's" help.

Comment: still its not working. please post problem snap shot.

Comment: xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" what is this line of code in menu.. remove this and check

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44085/discussion-between-sush-and-andrew-q)

Answer (score 3):

I can see this:

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

Change **app:showAsAction** to **android:showAsAction** and check.
Hope it will fix the problem.

Edited (on 30 Dec 2013):
Can you just copy paste following code in your menu.xml and see if it works

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_about"
        android:icon="@drawable/action_about"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/action_about"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
</menu>
```

There is only change of showAction for both the item.
I have this xml and its working fine at my end.

Comment: Nope this didn't solve it either. But thanks for correcting my code! I wouldn't have seen that.

Comment: If R.java is not getting generated check and resolve the errors in the XML files. Once those errors are resolved R.java file should get generated.

Comment: But there aren't any errors in the XML files. The R.java file is deleting itself when items are added to the file but the file has no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your last return statement `return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);` with either

`return true`; or `return false` based on your need as the method requires a `boolean` return statement .

Comment: Now it says "R" cannot be resolved to a type. I just cleaned the project and it's set to build automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In ADT go into "Navigate" (menu) --> Preferences --> Android --> Build --> Build Config: set this to build the output as "Normal". After doing this, clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: This seemed to work for about a minute. Now it's giving me an aapt.exe error.