# When i create new project R.java file missing, and There is no error in XML file

Tags: android, r.java-file

//R. gives error of "R cannot be resolved to a variable". 
i am trying to make a simple program but when i create the project it displays that "R cannot be resolved to a variable".

package com.example.ghanshyam;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //R cannot be resolved to a variable
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: look at  this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20822746/793943

Answer (score 0):

1. After installing `Android SDK Tools`, you should install `Android SDK Build-tools` using Android SDK Manager
2. Try adding some whitespace in `androidmanifest.xml` and then save the file
3. Try Clean and Rebuild the project

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it has worked for me:

```
Right-click on the Project root --> Android Tools --> Fix Project Properties
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont worry. First you may clean the project, then run the project. If this does not work then follow the following links:

Here is the best way to solve this problem: Android Development- [Where is my R.Java file?](http://www.mybringback.com/travis-android-help/1/hello-world/)

[R cannot be resolved - Android error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)

[R cannot be resolved to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592806/r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable)

[R cannot be resolved to a variable -- mailing list entry](http://www.anddev.org/sdk-adt-emulator-problems-f16/r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable-t52607.html)

[Fixed: R cannot be resolved to a variable](http://www.codeofaninja.com/2011/05/fixed-r-cannot-be-resolved-to-variable.html)